# What is the equivalent of the ga:productRemovesFromCart metric for ga4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to migrate my reports to ga4. But I couldn't find the ga4 equivalent of the following metrics. How can I do it

```
ga:productRemovesFromCart
ga:quantityAddedToCart
ga:quantityRemovedFromCart
ga:quantityCheckedOut
```